# JavaFX periodic background task

Tags: javafx

I try to run in JavaFX application background thread periodically, which modifies some GUI property.

I think I know how to use `Task` and `Service` classes from `javafx.concurrent` and can't figure it out how to run such periodic task without using `Thread#sleep()` method. It would be nice if I can use some `Executor` from `Executors` fabricate methods (`Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`)

I tried to run `Runnable` every 5 sec, which restarts `javafx.concurrent.Service` but it hangs immediately as `service.restart` or even `service.getState()` is called.

So finally I use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`, which fires my `Runnable` every 5 sec and that `Runnable` runs another `Runnable` using:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
 //here i can modify GUI properties
}
```

It looks very nasty :( Is there a better way to do this using `Task` or `Service` classes?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can use Timeline for that task:

```
Timeline fiveSecondsWonder = new Timeline(
                 new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), 
                 new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("this is called every 5 seconds on UI thread");
    }
}));
fiveSecondsWonder.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
fiveSecondsWonder.play();
```

for the background processes (which don't do anything to the UI) you can use old good `java.util.Timer`:

```
new Timer().schedule(
    new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("ping");
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: As i understand method handle(ActionEvent event) would be executed in UI main thread .So if computation of new value is long, i can get into troubles? I need to update simple text status, which is getting through network, so any problems with timeouts would block this thread - am i correct?

Comment: Also you may find useful `javafx.animation.AnimationTimer`

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Your first example does not work. When I run it there is no output on screen and program simply terminates.

Comment: @KshitizSharma this is code for JavaFX UI application, you can't just run it from main() method. See full example here: http://pastebin.com/tyLKxmB6

Comment: Note that a Timer thread is ok as long as it won't try to modify some of the javafx elements, otherwise it will raise an Exception... :o

Comment: I got Error : Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0

Comment: @NoorHossain look 2 comments above

Comment: so, for changing UI or elements, I have to use Platform.runLater ?

Comment: @NoorHossain, yep, unless you are already on the UI thread

Answer (score 54):

***Preface:** This question is often the duplicate target for questions which ask how to perform periodic actions in JavaFX, whether the action should be done in the background or not. While there are already great answers to this question, this answer attempts to consolidate all the given information (and more) into a single answer and explain/show the differences between each approach.*

*This answer focuses on the APIs available in JavaSE and JavaFX and not third-party libraries such as ReactFX (showcased in [Tomas Mikula's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026145/6395627)).*

---

## Background Information: JavaFX & Threads

Like most mainstream GUI frameworks, JavaFX is single-threaded. This means there's a single thread dedicated to reading and writing the state of the UI and processing user-generated events (e.g. mouse events, key events, etc.). In JavaFX this thread is called the "JavaFX Application Thread", sometimes shortened to just "FX thread", but other frameworks may call it something else. Some other names include "UI thread", "event-dispatch thread", and "main thread".

It is absolutely paramount that anything connected to the GUI showing on screen is only ever accessed or manipulated on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. The JavaFX framework is not thread-safe and using a different thread to improperly read or write the state of the UI can lead to undefined behavior. Even if you don't see any externally-visible problems, access to state shared between threads without the [necessary *happens-before* relationships](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) is broken code.

Many GUI objects, however, can be manipulated on any thread as long as they aren't "live". From the documentation of [`javafx.scene.Node`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> Node objects may be constructed and modified on **any thread as long they are not yet attached to a `Scene` in a `Window` that is [`showing`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#isShowing())** *[emphasis added]*. An application must attach nodes to such a Scene or modify them on the JavaFX Application Thread.

But other GUI objects, such as `Window` and even some subclasses of `Node` (e.g. `WebView`), are more strict. For instance, from the documentation of [`javafx.stage.Window`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html):

> Window objects must be constructed and modified on the JavaFX Application Thread.

If you're unsure about the threading rules of a GUI object, its documentation should provide the needed information. Though note that while a `Node` may be able to be created and modified on any thread before it is "live", it is still not thread-safe on its own. That is to say, it must only be modified by one thread at a time, where an appropriate *happens-before* relationship is established if and when passing the `Node` to another thread.

Since JavaFX is single-threaded you also have to make sure never to block or otherwise monopolize the FX thread. If the thread is not free to do its job then the UI is never redrawn and new user-generated events can't be processed. Not following this rule can lead to the infamous unresponsive/frozen UI and unhappy users.

It's virtually always wrong to [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

---

## Periodic Tasks

There are two different kinds of periodic tasks, at least for the purposes of this answer:

1. Periodic *foreground* "tasks".

   - This could include things such as a "blinking" node or periodically switching between images.
2. Periodic *background* tasks.

   - An example might be periodically checking a remote server for updates and, if there are any, downloading the new information and displaying it to the user.

### Periodic Foreground Tasks

If your periodic task is short and simple then using a background thread is overkill and just adds unnecessary complexity. The more appropriate solution is to use the [`javafx.animation`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) API. Animations are asynchronous but stay entirely within the *JavaFX Application Thread*. In other words, animations provide a way to "loop" on the FX thread, with delays between each iteration, without actually using loops.

There are three classes uniquely suited to periodic foreground tasks.

#### Timeline

A [`Timeline`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) is made up of one or more [`KeyFrame`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html)s. Each `KeyFrame` has a specified time of when it should complete. Each one can also have an "on finished" handler which is invoked after the specified amount of time has elapsed. This means you can create a `Timeline` with a single `KeyFrame` that periodically executes an action, [looping](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#cycleCountProperty) as many times as you want (including [forever](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#INDEFINITE)).

```java
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);

    // toggle the visibility of 'rect' every 500ms
    Timeline timeline =
        new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), e -> rect.setVisible(!rect.isVisible())));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); // loop forever
    timeline.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(rect), 200, 200));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Since a `Timeline` can have more than one `KeyFrame` it's possible to have actions being executed at different intervals. Just keep in mind that the times of each `KeyFrame` *do not stack*. If you have one `KeyFrame` with a time of two seconds followed by another `KeyFrame` with a time of two seconds, both `KeyFrame`s will finish two seconds after the animation is started. To have the second `KeyFrame` finish two seconds after the first one, its time needs to be *four* seconds.

#### PauseTransition

Unlike the other animation classes, a [`PauseTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) is not used to actually *animate* anything. It's main purpose is to be used as a child of `SequentialTransition` to put a pause between two other animations. However, like all subclassses of `Animation` it can have an "on finished" handler that's executed after it completes, allowing it to be used for periodic tasks.

```java
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);

    // toggle the visibility of 'rect' every 500ms
    PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(500));
    pause.setOnFinished(
        e -> {
          rect.setVisible(!rect.isVisible());
          pause.playFromStart(); // loop again
        });
    pause.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(rect), 200, 200));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Notice the on-finished handler invokes `playFromStart()`. This is necessary to "loop" the animation again. The `cycleCount` property can't be used since the on-finished handler is not invoked at the end of each cycle, it's only invoked at the end of the *last* cycle. The same thing is true of `Timeline`; the reason it works with `Timeline` above is because the on-finished handler isn't registered with the `Timeline` but with the `KeyFrame`.

Since the `cycleCount` property can't be used for `PauseTransition` for multiple cycles it makes it more difficult to loop only a certain number of times (rather than forever). You have to keep track of the state yourself and only invoke `playFromStart()` when appropriate. Keep in mind that *local variables* declared outside a lambda expression or anonymous class but used inside said lambda expression or anonymous class must be final or effectively final.

#### AnimationTimer

The [`AnimationTimer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) class is the lowest level of JavaFX's animation API. It's not a subclass of `Animation` and thus doesn't have any of the properties that were used above. Instead, it has an abstract method that, when the timer is started, is invoked once per frame with the timestamp (in nanoseconds) of the current frame: [`#handle(long)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html#handle(long)). In order to execute something periodically with `AnimationTimer` (other than once per frame) will require manually calculating the time differences between invocations of `handle` using the method's argument.

```java
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);

    // toggle the visibility of 'rect' every 500ms
    AnimationTimer timer =
        new AnimationTimer() {

          private long lastToggle;

          @Override
          public void handle(long now) {
            if (lastToggle == 0L) {
              lastToggle = now;
            } else {
              long diff = now - lastToggle;
              if (diff >= 500_000_000L) { // 500,000,000ns == 500ms
                rect.setVisible(!rect.isVisible());
                lastToggle = now;
              }
            }
          }
        };
    timer.start();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(rect), 200, 200));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

For most use cases similar to the above, using either `Timeline` or `PauseTransition` would be the better option.

### Periodic Background Tasks

If your periodic task is time-consuming (e.g. expensive computations) or blocking (e.g. I/O) then a background thread needs to be used. JavaFX comes with some concurrency utilities built-in to aid with communication between background threads and the FX thread. These utilities are described in:

- The [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) tutorial, and
- The documentation of the classes in the [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

For periodic background tasks that need to communicate with the FX thread, the class to use is [`javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html). That class will execute its task periodically, restarting after successful execution, based on a specified period. If configured to do so it will even retry a configurable amount of times after failed executions.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class App extends Application {

  // maintain a strong reference to the service
  private UpdateCheckService service;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    service = new UpdateCheckService();
    service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(5));

    Label resultLabel = new Label();
    service.setOnRunning(e -> resultLabel.setText(null));
    service.setOnSucceeded(
        e -> {
          if (service.getValue()) {
            resultLabel.setText("UPDATES AVAILABLE");
          } else {
            resultLabel.setText("UP-TO-DATE");
          }
        });

    Label msgLabel = new Label();
    msgLabel.textProperty().bind(service.messageProperty());

    ProgressBar progBar = new ProgressBar();
    progBar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    progBar.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
    progBar.visibleProperty().bind(service.stateProperty().isEqualTo(State.RUNNING));

    VBox box = new VBox(3, msgLabel, progBar);
    box.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    box.setPadding(new Insets(3));

    StackPane root = new StackPane(resultLabel, box);
    StackPane.setAlignment(box, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 200));
    primaryStage.show();

    service.start();
  }

  private static class UpdateCheckService extends ScheduledService<Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
      return new Task<>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
          updateMessage("Checking for updates...");
          for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            updateProgress(i + 1, 1000);
            Thread.sleep(1L); // fake time-consuming work
          }
          return Math.random() < 0.5; // 50-50 chance updates are "available"
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a note from the documentation of `ScheduledService`:

> Timing for this class is not absolutely reliable. A very busy event thread might introduce some timing lag into the beginning of the execution of the background Task, so very small values for the period or delay are likely to be inaccurate. A delay or period in the hundreds of milliseconds or larger should be fairly reliable.

And another:

> The `ScheduledService` introduces a new property called `lastValue`. The `lastValue` is the value that was last successfully computed. Because a `Service` clears its `value` property on each run, and because the `ScheduledService` will reschedule a run immediately after completion (unless it enters the cancelled or failed states), the `value` property is not overly useful on a `ScheduledService`. In most cases you will want to instead use the value returned by `lastValue`.

The last note means binding to the `value` property of a `ScheduledService` is in all likelihood useless. The example above works despite querying the `value` property because the property is queried in the `onSucceeded` handler, before the service is rescheduled.

#### No Interaction with UI

If the periodic background task does not need to interact with the UI then you can use the standard APIs of Java instead. More specifically, either:

- The [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html) class (*not* `javax.swing.Timer`),
- Or the more modern [`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) interface.

Note that `ScheduledExecutorService` supports thread *pools*, unlike `Timer` which only supports a single thread.

#### ScheduledService is not an Option

If for whatever reason you can't use `ScheduledService`, but need to need to interact with the UI anyway, then you need to make sure the code interacting with the UI, and only that code, is executed on the FX thread. This can be accomplished by using [`Platform#runLater(Runnable)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)).

> Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at some unspecified time in the future. This method, which may be called from any thread, will post the Runnable to an event queue and then return immediately to the caller. The Runnables are executed in the order they are posted. A runnable passed into the runLater method will be executed before any Runnable passed into a subsequent call to runLater. If this method is called after the JavaFX runtime has been shutdown, the call will be ignored: the Runnable will not be executed and no exception will be thrown.
>
> NOTE: applications should avoid flooding JavaFX with too many pending Runnables. Otherwise, the application may become unresponsive. Applications are encouraged to batch up multiple operations into fewer runLater calls. Additionally, long-running operations should be done on a background thread where possible, freeing up the JavaFX Application Thread for GUI operations.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a `runnable` to this method *happen-before* actions performed by the `runnable` in the JavaFX Application Thread.

Heed the note from the above documentation. The `javafx.concurent.Task` class avoids this by coalescing updates to its `message`, `progress`, and `value` properties. This is currently implemented by using an `AtomicReference` and strategic get-and-set operations. If interested, you can take a look at the implementation (JavaFX is [open source](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx)).

Comment: Excellent explanation, I'm still learning from it..!

Comment: Perfect explanation.

Answer (score 17):

I would Prefer the PauseTransition:

```java
PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
wait.setOnFinished((e) -> {
    /*YOUR METHOD*/
    wait.playFromStart();
});
wait.play();
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution using Java 8 and [ReactFX](http://www.reactfx.org). Say that you want to periodically recompute the value of `Label.textProperty()`.

```
Label label = ...;

EventStreams.ticks(Duration.ofSeconds(5))          // emits periodic ticks
    .supplyCompletionStage(() -> getStatusAsync()) // starts a background task on each tick
    .await()                                       // emits task results, when ready
    .subscribe(label::setText);                    // performs label.setText() for each result

CompletionStage<String> getStatusAsync() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getStatusFromNetwork());
}

String getStatusFromNetwork() {
    // ...
}
```

Compared to Sergey's solution, you don't dedicate the whole thread to getting status from the network, but instead use the shared thread pool for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ScheduledService`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) too. I am using this alternative after noticing that during the use of `Timeline` and `PauseTransition` occurred some UI freezes in my application, especially when the user interacts with the elements of a `MenuBar` (on JavaFX 12). Using the `ScheduledService` these problems no longer occurred.

```
class UpdateLabel extends ScheduledService<Void> {

   private Label label;

   public UpdateLabel(Label label){
      this.label = label;
   }

   @Override
   protected Task<Void> createTask(){
      return new Task<Void>(){
         @Override
         protected Void call(){
           Platform.runLater(() -> {
              /* Modify you GUI properties... */
              label.setText(new Random().toString());
           });
           return null;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And then, use it:

```
class WindowController implements Initializable {

   private @FXML Label randomNumber;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL u, ResourceBundle res){
      var service = new UpdateLabel(randomNumber);
      service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(2)); // The interval between executions.
      service.play()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was not easy find the way to programing this kind of behavior may be because my process reads I/O, works in milliseconds and I felt was often interrupted by GUI thread, but I made it by creating a `BackgroundProcess` class & with the help of `ScheduledExecutorService`.

In the controlle side, I use `PauseTransition` to read `volatile` (no contention) info only.

Sample code :

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    final BackgroundProcess backgroundProcess = new BackgroundProcess();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 720, 610);
        HelloController helloController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        helloController.setBackgroundProcess(backgroundProcess);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        scheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                backgroundProcess,
                0, 111, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        scheduledExecutor.shutdown();
    }

    ...

}



public class BackgroundProcess implements Runnable{
    volatile String status = "";

    @Override
    public void run() {
       status = newStatus();
    }

    ...

}    


public class HelloController {

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {

        PauseTransition refresh = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(111));
        wait.setOnFinished((e) -> {

            statusLabel.setText(backgroundProcess.status);

            refresh.playFromStart();
        });
        refresh.play();
    }

    ...

}
```

To read synchronized (contention) info I use `ScheduledService` to prepare the info and prevent interruptions in the JavaFX thread.

This is a more complex sample code:

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    final BackgroundProcess backgroundProcess = new BackgroundProcess();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 720, 610);
        HelloController helloController = fxmlLoader.getController();
        helloController.setBackgroundProcess(backgroundProcess);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        scheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                backgroundProcess,
                0, 111, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
        scheduledExecutor.shutdown();
    }

    ...

}



public class BackgroundProcess implements Runnable{
    volatile String status = "";
    LinkedTransferQueue<String> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue();

    @Override
    public void run() {
       status = newStatus();
       addToQueue();
    }

    ...

}    


public class HelloController {


    static class SynchronizedInformation {
        ArrayList<String> list;
    }

    private SynchronizedInformation prepareSynchronizedInformation() {
        if (backgroundProcess.queue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        final SynchronizedInformation r = new SynchronizedInformation();
        int size = backgroundProcess.queue.size();
        r.list = new ArrayList<>(size);
        String line;
        while (r.list.size() < size && null != (line = backgroundProcess.queue.poll())) {
            r.list.add(line);
        }

        return r;
    }

    private void refreshSynchronizedInformation(SynchronizedInformation synchronizedInformation) {
        if (null != synchronizedInformation) {
            synchronizedInformation.list.forEach(textArea::appendText);
        }
        statusLabel.setText(backgroundProcess.incoming);
    }

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        ScheduledService<SynchronizedInformation> svc = new ScheduledService<>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<SynchronizedInformation> createTask() {
                return new Task<SynchronizedInformation>() {
                    @Override
                    protected SynchronizedInformation call() throws Exception {
                        return prepareSynchronizedInformation();
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        svc.setDelay(Duration.millis(111));
        svc.setOnSucceeded(e -> refreshSynchronizedInformation(svc.getValue()));
        svc.start();


    ...

}
```